# Calculate the limit of $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2} -\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)$

Tags: limits

I want to calculate this limit and wonder what is the best way to calculate it.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2} -\frac{1}{1-x^3}\right)$$
I tried to do the following thing
 $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-}\left(\frac{1-x^3-(1-x^2)}{(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}\right)$$
What I get is $0$ but the answer is $+\infty$,What I`m doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from where you had stopped.

$$\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}\frac{x^{2}-x^{3}}{(1-x^{2})(1-x^{3})}=\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}\frac{x^{2}(1-x)}{(1-x^{2})(1-x^{3})}=\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}\frac{x^{2}}{(1+x)(1-x^{3})}=\frac{1}{(1-1)(1+1)}=\frac{1}{0\cdot2}=\infty$$

Comment: That's atrocious. By the same "argument" we can convince ourselves that $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)(1-x^3)}=\frac1{(1-1)(1+1)} =\frac{1}{0\cdot 2}=\infty,$$ when in fact $$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^2}{(1+x)(1-x^3)}=-\infty.$$ Don't just "plug it in" when you've got a zero denominator. Things aren't that simple.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: It might help if you use the formulas $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$ and $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$ to rewrite your denominators before you combine your fractions.